# Do estimates of effect size vary as a function of sample size?

Tags: statistical-power, meta-analysis, r-squared, effect-size

Imagine 50 studies of the same phenomenon with 100 participants, vs. 50 studies with 200 participants. Would we expect greater variation in estimates of effect size with a smaller number of participants?

I know that this is true for p-values, but is it also true for estimates of effect size?

If so, does this mean that an estimate of effect size from an underpowered study is unreliable?

Comment: Yes. That depends what you mean by "unreliable".

Comment: @JeremyMiles As in, less likely to be the "true" value.

Comment: Yes, there is a lot of research on small size bias and multiple small studies vs. one large studies.

Comment: @abousetta Thanks! Are there any you'd be able to point me to?

Comment: These are from a quick search and I'm sure there are more out there. https://jamanetwork.com/journals/jama/article-abstract/410030    https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5813486/

Comment: @abousetta Thanks!